# proving there is an injection from natural numbers to a set without the axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory

> Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal number. Prove, without appealing to the Axiom of Choice, that 
>   $$\aleph_0 \leq 2^{2^\kappa}$$

I am struggling to answer this question. If I had the axiom of choice available, I would have that there is an injection from natural numbers to k, by cardinal comparability. I'm not sure how to approach this question without axiom of choice being available.

Comment: Does the theorem that states that $|/mathcal P(X)|>|X|$ use axiom of choice?

Comment: @AndréPorto Cantor's theorem shows (without choice) that $$2^{2^\kappa}\gt2^\kappa\gt\kappa.$$ That does not in itself establish $$2^{2^\kappa}\ge\aleph_0$$ because, in the absence of the axiom of choice, we do not know that $\kappa\ge\aleph_0;$ as far as we know, $\kappa$ could be *incomparable* with $\aleph_0.$

Comment: Oh man! It's everything so confusing without choice!

Comment: Oh wait! Isn't it true, by the definition of infinite set, that $\aleph_0$ is comparable with any infinite set?

Comment: @AndréPorto No, that's not true. By definition, a set is infinite if it has more than $n$ elements for every natural number $n.$ In the real world, where the axiom of choice is true, every infinite set has cardinality $\ge\aleph_0.$ However, in some weird fantasy worlds where the axiom of choice fails, there are sets which can't be well-ordered; the cardinality of such a set is not equal to any aleph, and is not necessarily comparable with $\aleph_0.$

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking. Let X be an infinite set. Define $f:\aleph_0\to X$ as follows: $f(0)=x_0$ for some fixed $x_0$; For each $n$, $X$ must contain more than $n$ elements, so there exists $x_{n+1}$ in $X$ which is not in $\{f(x_0),...,f(x_n)\}$ and we define $f(n+1)=x_{n+1}$. This way we constructed an injective function from $\aleph_0$ to $X$. Then $aleph_0\leq |X|$ for every infinite set $X$. What am I missing?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think maybe choosing your xn+1 in X at each step requires the axiom of choice, since you've got infinitely many choices, and there's no obvious way of choosing these elements of X, since we have no order on X.

Comment: Well, now I guess I understood it. If my recursive definition was allowed, then I could prove that the product $\Pi_{i\in\mathbb N}X$ has an element $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...)$ such that $x_i\neq x_{j}$ whenever $i<j$. But actually without the axiom of choice, I couldn't even say that $\Pi_{i\in\mathbb N}X$ is non-empty. I got it now, thank you very much @bof and lkjhgfdsa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $S$ is an infinite set, we can define an injection $f:\mathbb N\to\mathcal P(\mathcal P(S))$ by setting
$$f(n)=\{X\subset S:X\text{ is an }n\text{-element set}\}.$$
This shows that $\aleph_0\le2^{2^\kappa},$ a result which I believe is due to Bertrand Russell. Of course it's actually a strict inequality; there is no bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(S)).$

Answer (score -1):

By assumption, there exists a non-surjective injective map $f\colon\kappa\to\kappa$.
Define $g_0=f$ and  recursively $g_{n+1}=f\circ g_n$. Finally, define $\Bbb \omega\to 2^{2^\kappa}$, $n\mapsto g_n(\kappa)$.

Comment: No, the assumption is that $\kappa$ is infinite, i.e., $\kappa\gt n$ for every natural number $n.$ Some kind of choice is needed to conclude that $\kappa$ is [Dedekind infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set), i.e., that there is a non-surjective injection $f:\kappa\to\kappa.$